# bad operator types for binary >

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Am trying to write a program to sort three numbers. Requirement is the three numbers are entered in a textfield. When compiling I get an error "bad operator types for binary <". Probably has something to do with me trying to get the int from a String, but can't solve it. How do I fixe it?

```
public class Oef0502 extends JFrame {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    JFrame frame = new Oef0502();
    frame.setSize( 400,200 );
    frame.setLocation( 400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane( new Panel() );       
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
static class Panel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField number1Field,number2Field,number3Field;
   public Panel() {
        ActionListener listener = new FieldHandler();

        number1Field = new JTextField( 10 );
        number1Field.addActionListener( listener );

        number2Field = new JTextField( 10 );
        number2Field.addActionListener( listener );

        number3Field = new JTextField( 10 );
        number3Field.addActionListener( listener );

        add( number1Field );
        add( number2Field );
        add( number3Field );
   }
   class FieldHandler implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) {
         String input1 = number1Field.getText();
         int number1 = Integer.parseInt( input1 );
         String input2 = number1Field.getText();
         int number2 = Integer.parseInt( input2 );
         String input3 = number1Field.getText();
         int number3 = Integer.parseInt( input3 );
         if (  input1  > input2  ) {
          int temp = input1;
          input1 = input2;
          input2 = temp; 
         }
         if ( input2 > input3 ) {
          int temp = input2;
          input2 = input3;
          input3 = temp;
         }
         if ( input1 > input2 ) {
          int temp = input1;
          input1 = input2;
          input2 = temp;
         }
       }
   }
 //line for giving the line back to the screen using paintComponent()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Strings with `>`. You should compare the parsed values you get from your Strings (number1, number2, number3). I.e., use `number1 > number2`, etc...

An alternative is to use `input1.compareTo(input2)>0` to compare the `String`s, but that would give you lexicographical order and not numeric order (if all the `String`s have the same number of characters, you'll still get the correct result with lexicographic order).

Comment: Thank you! Worked out great. And in retrospec it is really obvious why it didn't work :)